# write numbers and remainder in file, if remainder is 0 then display it on screen [bash script]

Tags: linux, bash

I have a scenario when you input two numbers (from 1 to 9) and it counts remainder of them (a % b). These numbers then are saved into a file and remainder. If remainder is 0 then these numbers and remainder need to be displayed on terminal screen.
NOTE: it needs to be done without if condition.

What I did:

```
echo Enter number:
read a
echo Enter another number:
read b
z=`expr $a % $b`
echo $a $b $z > file.txt
t=`expr $a % $b=0` echo $a $b $t
```

Problem is that I don't know how to do it without if condition when remainder is 0 and needs to be displayed on the terminal screen

Comment: Can you tell why you need it to work without an if condition?

Comment: it's written on assignment I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just so happens that "expr" has a non-zero exit code when the remainder is 0. We can use that exit code to run that satement conditionally:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter number:
read a
echo Enter another number:
read b
z=$(expr $a % $b)
echo $a $b $z > file.txt
expr $a % $b >/dev/null || echo $a $b $z
```

Output:

```
Enter number:
54
Enter another number:
2
54 2 0
```

Another output:

```
Enter number:
55
Enter another number:
2
```

Basically this works because the expr gives exit code 1 when the outcome is 0. Using the "||" we only run the next command when the previous had a non-zero exit code. The >/dev/null hides the "expr" output, I did not want to show the output, only use the error code.

Another way to do it, but this starts to look more like an if statement:

```
[ $(expr $a % $b) -eq 0 ] && echo $a $b $z
```

Basically, it's using the "[" program (it's in /usr/bin/[ ) to test if the output of the expr is 0. If that is so, it gives exit code 0 and we run the echo.

We can also usse the "test" program, which is the same as using the [ program:

```
test $(expr $a % $b) -eq 0 && echo $a $b $z
```